# Should this two tables be related?

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, innodb

I have an `account_table` and a `news_table`. A news can be created by an admin account.

The `account_table` has 4 columns which are:
1. account_id
2. username
3. password
4. user_type

The `news_table` has 5 columns which are:
1. news_id
2. title
3. message
4. created_by
5. created_on

If I were to make `account_id` a foreign key on `news_table`, that would mean if an admin is deleted, the news he reported will also get deleted which should not happen. And why would `account_id` be even related to `news_table` when there is a column named `created_by` which is populated by taking the session user when creating the news and inserting it together with the `title`, `message`, `created_on` columns.

I'm just really confused on what would be the best design for this little tables. Should every table in the database be connected to each other?

Comment: I would understand a table like `account_order` would be dependent on the account since the order should also be gone in case the user is deleted but in the case of the news, I think it should be a separate table with no connections because it should be there even if there aren't any accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using foreign keys it is up to you, it is not mandatory, it provides you with some functionality such as:

- Make sure that you don't get a row inserted with a invalid created_by
- When you delete an account, "if" you want, you can automate the news deletion so you don't keep news related to unexisting account
- And also from a design point of view if you load your sql structure into a tool like Mysql Workbench it will point you the connections between tables in a visual way

As for what worries you that deleting the account will cause the deletion of the news, that is not true.

When defining a foreign key, it will ask you what you want to do when the record gets deleted, also delete news, or set created_by to NULL. You should choose set to NULL so the news don't have to get deleted. If you don't know how to define foreign keys you could use a tool like phpmyadmin to do it.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot there were other options beside cascade. Although I think the best way to go is for them not to be related to each other since there are no dependencies to be made.

Comment: As long as you manually set created_by to NULL when deleting a account it will be fine. If you don't set it to NULL and you show somewhere the user's name you might get a error trying to access a database row that is not existing.

Comment: If I were to set it to null, the created_by will be null and the existing users won't be able to distinguish who created the news and I can't have that. I need to be able to show the users who created it even if the user who did create it left.

Comment: I agree to you about that specific case when you want to know who created it even if the user left.

Answer (score 0):

If you link the two tables, you can still delete the account while still keeping news, if the foreign is nullable. But then what is the use case of the relation? More likely the relation is not necessary in your use case.

If we always create the relation, a common object like account may be associated with many other things besides news. I would avoid creating the relation unless it is apparently necessary.

Comment: Yeah that was exactly what I wanted to say, there is no relationship between those two tables simply because they were designed to function without the other. But still, thank you for your help. I would up your answer but I still need 5 reps.